# Azure Stream Analytics - split one column to multiple rows

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I have a json input where I have value of data between square brackets in column A

I need to split the contents of column A into separate columns

Input:

[image]

I need to split that data into

[image]

SPLIT is not available.
Pls advice if I can achieve this using cross apply? substring? charindex?
Column A can square brackets values might change, some rows might have 4,some have 2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Input data does not seem to be of Json. If your data is comma separated array values, you can use [cross apply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/apply-azure-stream-analytics)  and convert each value into a separate row. Then you can use, substring function to convert them into separate columns.

Query:

```
select 
substring(Rowvalue.arrayvalue,2,1) as col1, 
substring(Rowvalue.arrayvalue,4,1) as col2, 
substring(Rowvalue.arrayvalue,6,1) as col3
from input i
CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(i.SensorReadings.columnA) AS Rowvalue
```

**Input data:**

[image]

**Output data:**

[image]